# Similar EventToCommand (behavior's) on Android

Tags: c#, android, silverlight, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

**Does exist a similar EventToCommand (behavior's) on Android?**

Example Silverlight/WPF:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <Commanding:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.EditEventTypeCommand,
                                                                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                   PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                      </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: what you want? As it is not necessary that the person who knows `Silverlight` also knows `android`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mvvmcross, then bindings exist for all events which have `EventHandler` signatures - so you can just use bindings like:

```
'Click':{'Path':'MyViewModelCommand'}
```

There are plenty of examples of this in the samples, plus there are several questions oh here - search for MvvmCross and click.

If you need to bind to an event which has an `EventHandler<T>` signature then you can add this yourself - see [mvvmcross touch command binding in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815893/mvvmcross-touch-command-binding-in-android)

Comment: I create cusotm bindings for GridView. How do I redeclaration ItemCommand? So to return the chosen Item.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Try the other questions on here or the samples. Or try writing a new full question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood your question (I don't know Silverlight) but you can do as follows:

In your XML:

```
<Button ...
android:onClick="onMyButtonClicked".../>
```

In your java file

```
public void onMyButtonClicked(View sender) { ... }
```

There are no other ways to specify event handlers in Android XML, I think. You can specify a lot of properties though.