# Create custom bindings Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvmcross

### How to create custom bindings for Windows Phone?

I need to do something like this (but this example for Android):
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815893/mvvmcross-touch-command-binding-in-android)

**Custom bindings in Android:**

```
public class LongClickEventBinding
    : MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly View _view;
    private IMvxCommand _command;

    public LongPressEventBinding(View view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _view.LongClick += ViewOnLongClick;
    }

    private void ViewOnLongClick(object sender, View.LongClickEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_command != null)
        {
            _command.Execute();
        }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        _command = (IMvxCommand)value;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _view.Click -= ViewOnLongClick;
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(IMvxCommand); }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }
}
```

*Excuse me for the improper question..*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you don't need to develop anything at all. Use Blend to apply & setup [CallMethodAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723947%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) built-in behavior, and implement public method in your VM class.

Answer (score 0):

WP7 doesn't expose Tap and Hold as an event.

However, I believe you can access this sort og thing in Wp7 and Wp8 using Gestures - e.g.

- http://blogs.claritycon.com/windowsphone7/2010/07/wp7-gesture-recognizer-and-behavior-triggers/
- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API